Panamerican cold current (Eternal La-Nina?)

Imagine the situation, if American continents were (not) slightly different shaped:

Bering strait wider and there is a gap in eastern aleutian islands for cold arctic water flow and its absense in west part of the islands (no Kuril current);

north american west coast, especially in Mexico and Central American countries, directed southwest to the equator to channel the much stronger California current;

all South America is moved ~2500 km west;

Antarctic Peninsula moves there, too;

Tierra del Fuego directed towards the peninsula for greater inflow of cold water;

the northern Peruvian, and then the Ecuadorian, Colombian and Panamanian coasts continue to be smooth (without bays, peninsulas, etc.) and directed to the northwest in a one curved line, where the Humboldt Current wiil join the California Current. From there, they flow west into the Pacific Ocean.




CO2 levels are preindustrial. On the map, red solid lines is continents coasts; dotted ones is approximate shapes for a general understanding of what the continents look like (they looks like real analogs outside west coasts); yellow lines is our currents.

Lithospheric plates have also changed together with the continents, the geological situation is also similar to the real one.


So, how will such a Pan-American cold current affect the climate of both Americas, in particular the season of cyclones from this and the other side of the continents? For the entire Pacific Ocean? How it affect ENSO cycle and the Earth's climate in general? Will the cold equatorial current reach Indonesia?

I cannot understand what a "cold Equatorial current" could be.

When Californian and Gumboldt currents merge and start to flow west (slightly north of the equator, on Equatorial countercurrent place), it should be at least 5 C colder than tropical waters at higher latitudes.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Why would a cold current stay on the surface in Equatorial warm seas?

Hello @blablablanos, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]! We're lenient with new users, but for future reference: (a) That comment by the automated Community BOT means your quesiton fails SE's basic idea of a good question. I suspect it's that you've asked a very broad question. Climate questions are among the most difficult to answer, so it's important to focus/narrow them as much as you can. And (b), you're allowed to ask only one quesiton per post - you're asking at least six. You might consider using our Sandbox to test your questions.
